# how to transform a string object into an array in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How do I transform a string object into an array?

In my code I can receive an array.
Example:

```
Eq = ["5f17283521ac387fc8eeca6a", "5f17283c21ac387fc8eecb78", "5f17285621ac387fc8eed109", "5f17286321ac387fc8eed3ca", "5f17286621ac387fc8eed433", "5f17286d21ac387fc8eed5c8", "5f17287221ac387fc8eed6c7", "5f17288621ac387fc8eeda69", "5f17288921ac387fc8eedb1d", "5f17289421ac387fc8eedd39", "5f17289521ac387fc8eedd93", "5f17289821ac387fc8eeddfc", "5f17296e21ac387fc8ef0a57"]
```

And I can simply receive an identification string as well.
Example:

```
Eq = "5f17296e21ac387fc8ef0a57"
```

How can I transform this string that comes into an array?

```
consulta_OS.each do |os|
  if os.equipment.map(&:to_s) != []
    eq_id = os.equipment_ids.map(&:to_s) #equipment_ids receive in array  else
    eq_id = os.equipment_id.to_s #equipment_id in string
  end
end
```

Comment: If the object can be either string or array, you can use Rails' `Array.wrap(string_or_array)` – it wraps the argument in an array unless it already is an array.

Comment: BTW, many Active Record methods happily accept both: id and array of ids. So there's maybe no need to convert it in the first place (depending on what you're trying to do)

Comment: @Stefan [`Kernel#Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) also conveniently maps `nil` to `[]`. An under appreciated tool that should be in everyone's toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
EQ = ["5f17296e21ac387fc8ef0a57"]
```

or in your case:

```
EQ = [os.equipment_id.to_s]
```

Comment: When I receive in string I receive eq = os.equipament_id.to_s  . How to apply in this case?

Comment: Use `eq_id = [os.equipment_id.to_s]` to place the id in an array.

Comment: Thank you very much